# Ubuntu 13.04 64bit will not boot after upgrading Motherboard, will donate $10 to Ubuntu if someone helps resolve before Monday

Tags: boot, 13.04, uefi

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on a custom computer. Yesterday I upgraded my mobo, cpu and memory. My old configuration was asus a8n-sli deluxe mobo and a AMD athlon 64 FX-60 Dual Core processor x 2 with 4 gb ram. My new configuration is gigabyte 990fxa-ud3 motherboard, a AMD fx-8350 cpu with 16gb ram. Everything else stayed the same (ie hard drive, gpu, etc.) except I removed the sound card and both DVD drives because they were outdated. After installing the new hardware I tried to boot linux from my HDD and got this screen: GNU GRUB version 2.00-13ubuntu3 with 4 options: ubuntu, advanced options for ubuntu, memory test (memtest86+), memory test (memtest 86+, serial console 115200)

When selecting ubuntu, i get this:

```
 Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems: -Boots args (cat /proc/cmdline) - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?) -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root does not exist. Dropping to a shell! BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8ubuntu1) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help" for a list of built in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

I can't enter help on that screen, the keyboard doesn't seem to work.

-I didn't find secure boot in the uefi; I also ctrl-f through the online manual and there isn't the word secure boot.

-When I "`try ubuntu without installing`" from the USB stick it ends up with the same message, `"BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8ubuntu1) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help" for a list of built in commands."`

If someone can get me up and running before Monday I will donate $10 to Ubuntu.